# Problem with Xilinx SDK - Failed to Scan JTAG Chain

Tags: fpga, xilinx, jtag

I am having an issue with running a simple Hello World program on the Trenz TE0720-01 board with a Zync 7020 FPGA. I have been following the tutorial to setup and run the Hello World program given [here](http://www.ece.unm.edu/~jimp/codesign/Vivado/VivadoHelloWorldTutorial.pdf).

I have no problem up until I have to program the FPGA, which it then gives me the error,

"Program FPGA failed. Reason: Failed to Scan JTAG Chain. Unknown error."

I am using a standard USB A-Male to Mini-B cable to connect the board to the host computer.
I am also running on Windows 7.

How can I fix this error and get my FPGA to program?

Comment: Can you run  imapct and access your FPGA outside EDK?

Comment: Just looked at your board and I am puzzled, how do you connect your PC to the board? This board does not have an integrated USB-to-JTAG interface like many other boards, so you must use the Xilinx (or alternative) cable for being able to communicate and program your FPGA.

Comment: @FarhadA So I am using a generic USB cable connected to a port on my host computer, with a mini usb attached to the board on by the Mini USB connector (see [here](https://wiki.trenz-electronic.de/display/4X5B/TE0701+Carrier+Board+for+TE07xx+Series+User+Manual), feature 19). Also, yes I have run iMPACT, but it also cannot scan the JTAG chain. I have installed the digilent plugin as well.

Comment: @FarhadA Also, I'm trying to get the program to run on the ARM processor, but is that pretty much the same thing as trying to program the FPGA (meaning is it the same issue with JTAG chain scanning)?

Comment: Can you share the image of what you see when you try to initialize the JTAG chain? Do you see the FPGA? The ARM processor or nothing? Have you checked the VCC and GND of the JTAG interface? If you don't see anything, then it means your JTAG chain is broken or your power is really bad or not strong enouugh.

Answer (score 1):

That tutorial is for a different board.

In particular, it appears [from the Trenz docs](https://wiki.trenz-electronic.de/display/4X5B/TE0701+JTAG+Programming+Guide) that their board is emulating a Digilent JTAG cable, not a Xilinx one.

I'm not sure that is automatically recognized by the "Auto Detect" option shown in Fig38 of the tutorial you are using - or even whether it is supported by Vivado at all...

I would suggest you try following the Trenz JTAG doc linked to above and check that you can successfully scan the chain with Impact first.

Comment: I just tried the steps in the link, but it gives me an error saying, "A problem may exist in the hardware configuration. Check that the cable, scan chain, and power connections are intact that the specified chain configuration matches the actual hardware, and that the power supply is adequate and delivering the correct voltage."

Comment: Sounds like you might have a hardware problem then.  You'll have to work from first principles - check the power is good (and clean), then check the JTAG lines are wiggling according to spec.

Comment: A lot of problem with JTAG is the lack of power, check the power and make sure you have the right voltage on it. Sometimes, if you only have a very low power supply, when you connect your JTAG cable, the voltage drops to a level that is not acceptable and that is when you get this kind of errors.